# JavaFX - How to refresh/hide icons from tray?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How can I refresh system tray (there are killed program icons) or just hide some icons I want? Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You mean window's system tray? If so I don't think it's a JavaFX problem, I've often (always?) seen this problem appear when a program crashed/was terminated and I doubt they were all coded with JavaFX

Comment: Yes, I mean Window's tray and I don't think it's Java problem, but I want to know if I can do this with Java ;)

Comment: I doubt Java has any specific API to handle that ; you would have to find how to do it from windows (you could ask on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)), then integrate that solution in Java (`ProcessBuilder` or `JNI`)

Comment: That's not bad idea. Thanks!